# Identifying words in perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I'm trying to go through a list of files that have words sashed together and break the words apart.

```
my @file_list = (
    'myfirstperlfile.pl',
    'mashpotatorecipes.pl',
    'badhaircuts.pl',
    'jonisntverygoodatsoftball.pl',
    'thatnewcomedianislol.pl',
);
```

My list could be delineated by anything, but for the example's sake, it could look like this.

```
my @delineated_file_list = (
    'my first perl file',
    'mash potato recipes',
    'bad haircuts',
    'jon isnt very good at soft ball',
    'that new comedian is lol',
);
```

In my particular case, there are a lot of files, so looking for static words isn't ideal.

What's the best for perl to know my,first,perl & file are separate words? I'm also worried about identifying abbreviations, misspelled or fake words.

Comment: What is the purpose of this -- why do you need the script names broken into words? In the context of that, what is the tolerance for errors?  You can't just parse a bundle of glued words correctly into language without any other clue.

Comment: I have two files, a plugin file and the file it is intended for.  The plugin file is named after the file that uses it. For example, cgi-bin/folder/new_folder/abc_script.pl would use a plugin called cgibin_folder_newfolder_abcscript.pm.  Some files aren't following the formatting, so I want to write a test that looks at cgibin_folder_newfolder_abcscript.pm and can then see if its parent script exists.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't see that it takes _language_ to do that (which is a good thing since that is hard :).  As you pick a file whose ancestry you need to search for, use regex on each filename from the list of files in the directory where the parent is expected to be. You are searching for matching words after all, right? Regex can do that with all the flexibility you need, without going into a language analysis.

Comment: A trivial exampe: `my $patt = qr/abc.*script/i; for (@files) { if (/$patt/) { ... } }`, where you build `$patt` to account for the expected variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely you're going to find a perfect solution without developing an AI. But to start with you need a module that knows English words, so look in the [Lingua::EN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Lingua%3A%3AEN) namespace. [Lingua::EN::Segment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Segment) looks similar to your use case.

Comment: The reason why best summarized by this 5 second clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raka8Gxmqwc

Comment: On a serious note, there won't be a perfect solution: `island.pl`  `is land` or `island`

Comment: First of all, that's hilarious. And second, lovely. :)